# Which chip in this image is the main CPU for the Samsung Galaxy 3

Tags: mobile

Which chip is the main CPU in this photo?

The image was taken from there. [Samsung Galaxy 3](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/news/ifixit_chipworks_samsung_galaxy_s_iii_teardown)

[image]

Comment: Are you kidding? The largest IC is shown at 5 mm wide, 90% of the picture is mechanical parts!

Comment: seriously? was it that bad of a question. lol

Comment: Hey, only one of the downvotes is mine! :-)

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini I also down-voted and up-voted stevenh's comment. In general case, if this was some unidentified device, we'd be unable to determine the parts with a picture such as this. The single most important thing when expecting someone to decode a circuit from a photo is to provide picture(s) with all part numbers readable. The second would be to provide both sided of the board. In my opinion the linked image does not qualify and the only way we can actually determine what is pictured is by knowing it in advance from some other source.

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini I'll exaggerate a little bit in this example, but I think that it will make the point: Imagine someone showed you a satellite picture of a rock concert and asked you to find a certain person there. Yes, we can in general see that it is a large gathering of the people and yes, we can roughly see some larger objects, but we can't give positive identification of a single person.

Comment: no problem guys, when I saw the photo my first thought was that the little chip on the board was to small to be the CPU. I can see now how there really isn't enough detail to decode anything meaningful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of them; it's on the other side of the circuit board on top.

[Ifixit's teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung-Galaxy-S-III-Teardown/9391/1#.T8uHpD4tgY4) shows it quite clearly. The [orange chip in this picture](http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/qneCB1ZDEXXKkcum.huge) is the Exynos SoC.